# Find committed files that should have been ignored

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

How can I list all files in a repository that were committed (explicitly), although they were ignored because of the .hgignore file

- .hgignore uses glob syntax
- running on Windows
- it's not necessary to take any *global* .hgignore file into account

My idea:
hg manifest > filter using the content of .hgignore > result

Comment: You cannot pipe the manifest into a _filter_ of .hgignore. However, you can list the files you want by using the method described in the Mercurial TipsAndTricks: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Remove_files_that_are_matched_by_.hgignore_but_were_added_in_error

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn and use filesets in this case

List files that are in .hgignore but are already tracked:

`hg locate "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"`